# How to check if file already uploaded to AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

In my application I want to prevent reuploading a file to AWS S3. I found the AWS JavaScript headObject useful

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property

But I not only want to compare the file name but also its content.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Common Response Headers - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html):

> Objects encrypted by SSE-S3 or plaintext have ETags that are an MD5 digest of their data

If your object meet this criteria, you can perform an MD5 on the local file and compare it with the ETag returned by `headObject()`. If they match, then the contents is the same.

Comment: does aws provide any library to calculate file's MD5?

Comment: How about file uploaded with multipart upload?

Comment: An ETag is not an MD5 for files uploaded by multi-part copy. MD5 is a standard operation. Functions/libraries are available in all programming languages, it is not specific to AWS.

Comment: Hi @John Rotenstein,  Can we achieve that without using any third part library? Does aws provide any way to compare file with content not just by key?

Comment: No, there is no "compare" functionality provided.